# Make movement speed relative to player character rotation in Unity?

Tags: unity, movement, vector

I'm doing a strict topdown 2D game where the character looks at wherever the mouse is pointing (same perspective as GTA 2 or Darkwood) . I want to make movement speed for strafing and backing up slower than walking forward. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this using Angle() and understanding vector math.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are the movement controls? If I press W, do I walk upward on the screen, or forward toward the mouse?

Comment: Sorry for not giving this information earlier. If you press W, you walk upward on the screen.

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/top+down+movement+unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product between the movement vector and character’s looking vector will give you a scale between -1 and 1. This could help you scale your movement based on the angle that the movement differs from the looking direction.

You could also just get the absolute value of angle between these vectors and have different cases like if > 80 degrees, slow by 50% (strafing) if > 160% slow by 75% (backwards)